Bluetooth errors when waking from suspend
I installed Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon on my brand new Asus laptop and I get these errors when waking from suspend:
Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c24 failed: -112
Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0c1a

Which are also visible in dmesg. Bluetooth and everything else is working fine but I don't like seeing error messages everytime I start using my computer.
I know I can ignore them – but why are these errors showing? And if there is no problem can I hide them? –
